# error compiling my ionic app using ionic package

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to build a release version of my Ionic app for android, using `$ ionic package build android --release --profile profile_production`, but I get the following error. Can you help please ?

Nota: `ionic build android` leads to no error.

```
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:11: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
                                  ^
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:12: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
                                  ^
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:13: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
                                  ^
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:193: error: cannot find symbol
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, email, scope);
                    ^
  symbol: variable GoogleAuthUtil
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:202: error: cannot find symbol
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, email, scope);
                    ^
  symbol: variable GoogleAuthUtil
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:205: error: cannot find symbol
            GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken(context, token);
            ^
  symbol: variable GoogleAuthUtil
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:210: error: cannot find symbol
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, email, scope);
                    ^
  symbol: variable GoogleAuthUtil
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:213: error: cannot find symbol
            GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken(context, token);
            ^
  symbol: variable GoogleAuthUtil
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
        catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userAuthEx) {
               ^
  symbol: class UserRecoverableAuthException
/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/GooglePlus.java:227: error: cannot find symbol
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                 ^
  symbol: class GoogleAuthException
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
10 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.201 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildRelease,-b,/home/package/workspace/apps-bc689f0f-142/cordova/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Answer (score 0):

First time answering here, but this post worked for me, so I think I got to paste it here.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/252

What i did change was the plugin installed, instead of the cordova normal plugin, i added the git one, like this code:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid`